# In bash, how are infinite output streams redirected to files handled?

Tags: bash, file, io-redirection

As an experiment, I redirected the output of `yes`, which is a command that [outputs a string repeatedly until killed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes), as follows:

```
yes > a.txt
```

I interrupted the process with Ctrl + C in a split of a second but even in that short time a.txt ended being a couple hundred megabytes in size.

So, I have several questions:

1. How can such a large file be generated at such a short time? Aren't there writing speed restrictions, especially on HDDs like the one I am using?
2. How can I avoid this when I unintentionally redirect the output of a program with an endless loop?
3. Assume the process above works for a long time. Will all the space left in storage be filled eventually or are there any "safety measures" set by bash, OS, etc.?

Comment: A split second to a human is a thousand generations of computing history. How many books have we written in 1000 generations?

Comment: Computers do what you tell them. That's a good thing. If you don't want to make big files, don't tell them to make big files. You're the programmer. That said, most OSs support per-user and/or per-process limits on resources. Explore those for the system you're using. (You didn't mention that.)

Comment: 1. Just because it's in memory doesn't mean the data has made it to disk yet. 2. set process limits (eg. bash has `ulimit -f`) 3. it will probably be filled

Comment: On a SSD things happen pretty fast...

Comment: With ext4, you can control the percentage reserved at the time the filesystem is created with the `-m reserved-blocks-percentage` option. (check `man mkfs.yourfs` to determine availability for `yourfs`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output is kept in kernel buffers temporarily. When your memory fills up, then the writing will slow down to hard disk velocity, which is still pretty fast.

Most Unix filesystems reserve a percentage of space for root processes. You can see this by comparing the output of `df` with `sudo df`. But unless you have user quotas enabled, you can certainly use all your disk space up like that. Fortunately, the `rm` command-line tool doesn't need to consume disk storage to do its work.

Comment: FWIW, `rm` can fail if you have a filesystem like ZFS or BTRFS which do copy-on-write, if you fill the disk after previously creating any snapshots...